# What should I do about this random iPhone crash in WebCore?

Tags: iphone, crash, uiwebview, webkit

This happens at random intervals.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Obviously it has to do with the UIWebView, but not sure what's going on.

```
Thread 1 Crashed:
0   WebCore                             0x0006eb56 WebCore::ScrollView::repaintContentRectangle(WebCore::IntRect const&, bool) + 10
1   WebCore                             0x0005ad88 WebCore::FrameView::doDeferredRepaints() + 32
2   WebCore                             0x0005ad00 WebCore::FrameView::endDeferredRepaints() + 104
3   WebCore                             0x00050818 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 844
4   WebCore                             0x000504c4 WebCore::FrameView::layoutTimerFired(WebCore::Timer<WebCore::FrameView>*) + 4
5   WebCore                             0x000504ae WebCore::Timer<WebCore::FrameView>::fired() + 26
6   WebCore                             0x000502c6 WebCore::TimerBase::fireTimers(double, WTF::Vector<WebCore::TimerBase*, 0ul> const&) + 102
7   WebCore                             0x0004fd1e WebCore::TimerBase::sharedTimerFired() + 66
8   WebCore                             0x0004fcb2 WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 34
9   CoreFoundation                   0x00056bac CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2112
10  CoreFoundation                   0x00056356 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 42
11  WebCore                            0x0005d6b2 RunWebThread(void*) + 286
12  libSystem.B.dylib                0x0002490a _pthread_body + 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Report it to Apple. And explain them how you are using the WebView. Or explain us here, maybe you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Also check if this is reproducable on several different SDK Simulator versions. This may help to detect if the error is on your side or is in the SDK.